# Java - Download https page

Tags: java, https

I'm trying to download the content of a webpage with this code, but it does not get the same as Firefox.

```
URL url = new URL("https://jumpseller.cl/support/webpayplus/");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
Files.copy(is, Paths.get("/tmp/asdfasdf"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

When I check `/tmp/asdfasdf` it is not the html source code of the page, but just bytes (no text). But still, in Firefox I can see the webpage and its source code

How can I get the real webpage?

Comment: I work at Jumpseller.cl. Feel free to email us and we can provide you the full content of the file (considering you will provide adequate credit to us).

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the response headers.  The page is compressed.  The `Content-Encoding` header has a value of `gzip`.

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL("https://jumpseller.cl/support/webpayplus/");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

if ("gzip".equals(conn.getContentEncoding())) {
    is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
}

Files.copy(is, Paths.get("/tmp/asdfasdf"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HtmlUnit library and this code:

```
    try(final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5 * 1000);         
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://jumpseller.cl/support/webpayplus/");
        String stringToSave = page.asXml(); // It's a string with full HTML-code, if need you can save it to file.
        webClient.close();  
    }
```